# How to use signalR in blazorise

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, blazorise

I'm using SignalR in asp.net core on server side and blazorise on client side. before I've used SignlaR basically just to chat and now I wanna use it to update a table when a record is inserted in some where else.
I think everything is ok on server side because as I trace it on server, it posts correct values but it does not update the table on client side. I don't know what's wrong.
here is my code on server side which is in a hub:

```
public async Task SendCartableUpdate(ResultData<PersonnelStationsInfo> resultData)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("RefreshCartable",resultData);
    }
```

and this is how I use it on client side:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        //await base.OnInitializedAsync();
        user = CurrentUserService.CurrentUser;
        await CartableTableChangePage(1);

        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("http://localhost:15424/ProductionServiceHub"))
    .Build();
        hubConnection.On<ResultData<PersonnelStationsInfo>>("RefreshCartable", (_resultData) =>
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        });
        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }
```

thanks for your helping

Comment: I have to mention that I have used signalr for chat in the same project

Comment: I have to mention one more thing, some times this code gives me the correct result. I have to say  it seems to be working randomly!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it and I'm so excited :)
here is how I changed my code on server side:

```
public async Task SendCartableUpdate()
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("RefreshCartable");
    }
```

and this how I changed my code on client side:

```
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    //await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
.WithUrl(navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("http://192.168.2.72:1050/ProductionServiceHub"))
.Build();
    hubConnection.On("RefreshCartable", () =>
    {
        CallLoadData();
        StateHasChanged();
    });
    await hubConnection.StartAsync();

    user = CurrentUserService.CurrentUser;
    await CartableTableChangePage(1);
}

private void CallLoadData()
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await CartableTableChangePage(1);
        StateHasChanged();
    });
}
```